# Fallback to copy constructor not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, c++14, move-semantics

I thought that when I delete the move constructor in `B` then the following code will still compile fine since it should still take the copy constructor to construct `B` objects. Why does the compiler now complain. Without the `=delete` it did not and called the copy constructor anyway since it was not allowed to provide a default move constructor!)

```
class B{
    public:
    B(){}
    ~B(){}
    B & operator=(const B & b){
        std::cout << " cannot move -> copy " << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    B(const B & v){
        std::cout << " cannot move -> copy " << std::endl;        
    }

    // B(B && b) = delete; // uncomment this!
};


int main()
{
    B b( B{} ); 
}
```

Compiler Output with clang 3.6 ([Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5c3a0a5eaca2af1))

```
main.cpp:27:7: error: call to deleted constructor of 'B'

    B b( B{} );

      ^  ~~~

main.cpp:21:5: note: 'B' has been explicitly marked deleted here

    B(B && b) = delete;

    ^

1 error generated.
```

Comment: "A function is not defined" and "a function is defined as deleted" are not the same thing. The latter means the function participates in overload resolution normally, then an error is produced if it is actually selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function with a deleted definition is still declared. Among other things, it participates in overload resolution normally - but if the overload resolution actually selects it, the program is ill-formed (**[dcl.fct.def.delete]/2**):

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.
>   *[ Note:* This includes calling the function implicitly or explicitly and forming a pointer or pointer-to-member
>   to the function. It applies even for references in expressions that are not potentially-evaluated. If a function
>   is overloaded, it is referenced only if the function is selected by overload resolution. *—end note ]*

This is different from a function that was never declared at all. A declaration that does not exist does not, of course, participate in overload resolution.

Comment: There's one exception: a *defaulted* move constructor or move assignment operator that's defined as deleted is ignored by overload resolution.